# Why doesn't my Mongo aggregation work properly on nested document?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have the following classes:

```
@Document(collection = "rCollection")
public class R{
    public R() {
    }
    @Id
    private String id;

    @TextIndexed(weight=2)
    private String fp;

    @TextIndexed(weight=1)
    private String sp;

    @DBRef
    @Indexed
    private P p;

    @DBRef
    private User user;
    private String date;
}
```

And:

```
@Document(collection = "pCollection")
public class P {

    public P() {}

    @Id 
    private String id;
}
```

What I would like to do is to search in `RCollection` and `group` the results based on the `p` element of the class. As the `id` in the `P` class is unique, I try to group the results based on `p.id`.
I have the following code in my repository:

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(text);
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("p.id");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group);

AggregationResults<finalResults> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "rCollection", finalResults.class);

List<finalResults> result= results.getMappedResults();

System.out.println("size is: "+result.size());
System.out.println("output = "+result.get(0).toString());
```

The code works fine, when I use `fp` instead of `p.id` in the above code. But if I use `p.id`, I see that the result is null. `result.size()` is 1, but `result.get(0).toString()` is null. That is, the following output:

```
size is: 1
output = FinalResults [fp=null, sp=null]
```

Here is my `finalResults` class (it is actually exactly the same as the `R` class):

```
private class FinalResults{

    public finalResults() {
    }
    private String id;

    private String fp;
    private String sp;

    private P p;
    private User user;
    private String date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FinalResults [fp=" + fp + ", sp=" + sp +"]";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Sample data:
Everything I have in `rCollection`:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9db54c3b4b97129065b773"),
 "_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.R", 
"fp" : "hello\ni\nam\n",
"sp " : "hi",
"date" : "Mon Apr 20 16:44:28 CEST 2020",
"p" : DBRef("p", ObjectId("5e9db54c3b4b97129065b772")),
"user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5e5aa321383ba54434092e8d"))
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e9db7903b4b97129065b775"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.R", 
"fp " : "hi",
"sp " : "hello",
"date" : "Mon Apr 20 16:54:08 CEST 2020",
"p" : DBRef("p", ObjectId("5e9db7903b4b97129065b774")),
"user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5e6e567dc77ed32ab4ad796b"))
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9db7a73b4b97129065b777"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.R",
"fp" : "hi",
"sp" : "",
"date" : "Mon Apr 20 16:54:31 CEST 2020",
"p" : DBRef("p", ObjectId("5e9db7a73b4b97129065b776")),
"user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5e6e567dc77ed32ab4ad796b"))
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9ef7e04b6e5d338c02fda0"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.R",
"fp" : "hello",
"sp" : "",
"date" : "Tue Apr 21 15:40:48 CEST 2020",
"p" : DBRef("p", ObjectId("5e9ef7e04b6e5d338c02fd9f")),
"user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5e5aa321383ba54434092e8d"))
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9ef82b4b6e5d338c02fda3"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.R",
"fp " : "hello",
"sp" : "",
"date" : "Tue Apr 21 15:42:03 CEST 2020",
"p" : DBRef("p", ObjectId("5e9ef82b4b6e5d338c02fda2")),
"user" : DBRef("user", ObjectId("5e9ef81f4b6e5d338c02fda1"))
}
```

And the relevant part from `pCollection`:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e9db54c3b4b97129065b772"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.P",
"p_name" : "Hisar",
"longitude" : 75.7216527,
"latitude" : 29.1491875
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9db7a73b4b97129065b776"),
"_class" : "com.main.tothepoint.model.P",
"p_name" : "Helsinki",
"longitude" : 24.9383791,
"latitude" : 60.16985569999999
}
```

The data has some more elements than the first part of my question, because I had tried to make my sample classes as small as possible.
In my code, I would like to search for texts which can exist in `fp` and`sp`, for example, I search for "hi" and then I see the size of my result to be 2187.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("p.id");
```

In MongoDB shell, it would be like this:

```
{$group:{ _id:"$p._id" }}
```

As you see, your group stage is not complete. You need to accumulate `fp` and `sp` fields in Group stage. To acumulate all possible values for `fp` and `sp` fields, we need use `$push` (array with duplicate values) or `$addToSet` (set with unique values) opertors and add extra `$unwind`'s. stages.

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(text);
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("p.id").push("fp").as("fp").push("sp").as("sp");
UnwindOperation unwindFp = Aggregation.unwind("fp");
UnwindOperation unwindSp = Aggregation.unwind("sp");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group, unwindFp, unwindSp);

AggregationResults<finalResults> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(R.class), FinalResults.class);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The fp's and sp's can be different.
Sorry, I'm really new to spring boot and mongodb, I know .push("fp").as("fp") but I don't know how to implement a combination of push and addToSet. (Or did I understand your answer wrongly?) Could you explain it a little bit more?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1419243 Updated my answer, please check again. You can reproduce your query in https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it still doesn't work correclty. I don't get the null items anymore, but my output has a size of 2187 now, though I have only 5 items in my database, out of which 3 cases have the search string and from these three items, 2 of them, share the same place.id. So, I expect to get two groups with all in all 3 items.

Comment: @user1419243 post please sample data

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks again for following up.

Comment: when I look at the logs, I see the following code:
: Executing aggregation: { "aggregate" : "r" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$text" : { "$search" : "hi"}}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$p.p_name" , "fp" : { "$push" : "$fp"} , "sp" : { "$push" : "$sp"} } , { "$unwind" : "$fp"} , { "$unwind" : "$sp"}] , "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 2147483647}}
which seems to be wrong. Doesn't it?